# Why are JS class instance properties null after setting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, async-await

This is a nodejs / express MVC app. I've got a custom model called MyModel (not really, but for privacy, let's pretend that's the name). The properties of the class are set as null by default:

```
export class MyModel {

    /* ----- FIELDS ----- */
    protected _id: string = null;
    protected _name: string = null;
    ...
```

The constructor only sets the name property, all other properties are set by database triggers. So in my save method (which persists to the db), it works kind of like this:

```
    async save() {
        let client:PoolClient = null;
        try {
            client = await pool.connect();
            let query;
            if (this._id === null) {
                query = {
                    name: 'insertMyModel',
                    text: 'INSERT INTO my_model (name) VALUES ($1::text) RETURNING id',
                    values: [this._name],
                    rowMode: 'array',
                };

            } else {
                ...
            }

            const result = await client.query(query);
            if (this._id === null) {
                this._id = result.rows[0][0];
                ...
```

The controller, simply (for now) returns MyModel to string, which should show the returned id.

```
    public async new(req, res) {
        try {
            const mymodel = await MyModel.new(req.params.name);

            res.send(mymodel.toString());
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error);
        }
    }
```

And (thank you @Barmar for noticing) I forgot to include MyModel's new function, so adding that here. This constructs the new MyModel instance and then calls save.

```
    public static async new(name: string) : Promise<GekModel> {
        if (name === undefined || name === null || (name = name.trim()) === '') {
            name = uniqueNamesGenerator();
        }

        const mymodel = new MyModel(name);
        mymodel.save();
        return mymodel;
    }
```

Using interactive debugging, I've determined that in the save method, indeed, the db is propertly returning the ID. And I've seen that in the save method, the returned id is assigned to the _id property. However, by the time I get back to the controller's new, the _id property is back to null. boink.

I assume this has something to do with the async nature of it? But, I'm at a loss. Would love any ideas!

Comment: This looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript. Am I right?

Comment: You're setting the properties of a specific instance in `save()`. But when you create a new instance, it gets the initial defaults.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this is Typescript, I've now added that as a tag. Also, thank you for asking about save / specific instance. I forgot to include the 'new' static method on the model. I added it above. The gist is that you call the static new method if you want to construct a new MyModel and save it to the DB all in one. That hydrated model instance is then returned.

Comment: I still don't understand what you think the problem is. Where do you use `_id` in the controller's `new`?

Comment: @Barmar The code flow is:
controller.new -> mymodel.new -> mymodel.save
New constructs a mymodel then saves it. In save you can see towards the bottom where after the database insert happens, the id value is retrieved and set in the _id property. I have validated that this part all works fine.

Comment: Add clarifications to the question, not a comment. It would be best if you posted a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks @Barmar for the suggestion of writing a minimal code reproducible version of this problem. I was able to whittle it down to 24 lines and realized that the problem was in the mymodel.save() line. I was calling save synchronously, when it's an async method. Therefore the toString() method was getting called before the id was set. I added an "await" before that and it's working now.